# Copying zero-terminated raw buffer of bytes to String

Tags: delphi, type-conversion, ansi-c

Sorry for all these questions I keep asking.Anyways my question is
am I properly converting the value to a string?(Not an unincode string).

```
const
address:dword=$0057B568;
var
a:string;
len,i:dword;
begin
len:=0;
repeat
inc(len);
until ((pbyte(address+len)^=0));//and(pbyte(address+1)^=0));(for unincode)

for I:=0 to len do
a:=a+chr(pbyte(address+I)^);
//stringreplace(a,#0,'',[rfreplaceall,rfignorecase]);
MessageBox(0,pchar(a),'',0);
end.
```

Comment: While for zero-terminated string u can use the typecast as Rob pointed below, i suggest u also learn the following standard procedures: Move, SetLength, SetString

Comment: Code indentation is really important. You should use indentation.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, it's not correct. The code is off by one byte. First, it assumes the string is at least one character long by ignoring the first byte. Next, it  copies one extra byte. Your code can be greatly simplified:

```
a := PAnsiChar(address);
```

Comment: Sicne his code shows traces of unicode buffers too, i'd add to ur answer both PWideChar and PAnsiChar and both AnsiString and UnicodeString/WideString